# Migrate a Sybase 12.5 DB to MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sybase, migration

I was wondering if anyone can help me. I want to Migrate a Sybase 12.5 DB to MSSQL 2005. But have no Idea where to start. and will all the Procedures still work that has been created in Sybase?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I did in the past was to use a 3rd party tool (couldn't quite get the Microsoft Data Transformation Service to do this) - for example RazorSQL (http://www.razorsql.com). There's a 30 day trial on it and you can use it in order to connect to the Sybase db server and dump all of the tables into CSV files.

You can then bulk insert those files into your MS SQL server.

Hope this help.

Regards,
Borislav

Comment: I think talend.com can help. There is a free version available.